# Magento Subtotal and grand Total is Empty in Cart Page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9.1

My Theme`s cart page is not showing subtotal n Grand total before it was working fine, its of rwd theme.

[image]

Even if i change my theme to default Facing same issue same issue in Magento`s default theme

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your `system / configuration / advanced`. My client had similar problem when `Mage_Tax` was disabled. Also try to enable another modules, which are disabled

Comment: @Cristik Vote up Requires 15 reputation i have only 11 :)